# React hook state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a react component (child) which takes JSON/Object array as input (from Parent) as props.

Json looks something like this

```
const inputFields = [
  {
    key: 'name', 
    type: 'text', 
    label: `Your Full Name`,
    helper: 'Using your real name would make it more likely for you to get a match',
    templateOptions: { 
      placeHolder: 'Frank Murphy',
      templateStyle: styles.textStyle // refer to the style component
    }
  }, 
  {
    key: 'dob', 
    type: 'dateTyper', //change this to Dob component
    label: 'Your Date of birth',
    helper: 'Your Birthdate will help us in connecting you with people of similar age',
    required: true
  }]
```

And in my child component i am rendering it. In this object-array notice a key required in the second Object `required: true`

Now, In my child component I have touchableOpacity which I enable/disable based on this state. So here is a rough structure of my child component.

```
export const Component = (props) => {
  const { inputFields } = props
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const currentComponent = inputFields[index]
  const {key, type, label, helper, buttonText, validator, required} = currentComponent
  console.log(required) // This is changing 
  const [mainButtonState, setButtonState] = useState(required)
```

And then a JSX of touchable component would look like this

```
 <TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={getValueFromState}
    disabled={mainButtonState}
    > 
    <Text> {usedButtonText} </Text> 
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

here onPress would just increment the state of `index`.

The problem I am facing is when, the state is incremented, my required which is `undefined` in the first object of inputFields is now `true`.

With this, I was hoping my button would be disable but my button is still active and my mainButton state is not set to `true` rather it is still `undefined`  Can someone help me in figuring out how I should change the `mainButtonState` here?

Comment: You say you're passing `inputField` as props, but I don't see you referencing `props` anywhere inside your child component.

Comment: @JMadelaine The above code contains only the part which I think is relevant. Anyway, Adding it now in the snippet :)

Comment: Did my answer help you solve the issue? If so could you mark it as the accepted answer so the question can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
const currentComponent = inputFields[index]
const {key, type, label, helper, buttonText, validator, required} = currentComponent
console.log(required) // This is changing 
const [mainButtonState, setButtonState] = useState(required)
```

You're getting mixed up between initialization and updating variables.

So here is what happens:

On first render you:

- initialize `index` to `0`.
- set `currentComponent` to `inputFields[0]`
- initialize `mainButtonState` to `undefined` (because `currentComponent.required` is `undefined`)

When you fire the `onPress` event, you increment `index`, which causes a second rerender.

On second rerender you:

- set `currentComponent` to `inputFields[1]`

And that's it.

Yes, `currentComponent.required` is now `true`, but this has nothing to do with the value of `mainButtonState`.

Initialization only happens on first render, so your `mainButtonState` value remains `undefined`.

To set `mainButtonState`, you need to call `setButtonState`. I would also change the setter function name to `setMainButtonState` to match the variable name, as it is bad practice to name the setter function differently than the variable. Setter functions should be the name of the variable they set, prefixed with "set".